# How do l fix a "Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT" when creating a new react-native project with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

After running this command `npx expo install react-dom react-native-web @expo/webpack-config` i get an error like this :

```
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I tried clearing the cache using `npm cache clean --force` and after that l deleted the node_modules and run `npm install`. But still l still face that error when l run that command.